# libcurl can't get CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL

Tags: c++, c, linux, libcurl

I use `curl_easy_getinfo` to get url, but **sometimes** it points to private memory, how can I solve it?

```
102 bool bb_curl::check_result(CURLcode code, CURL *handle, bool check_url) {
103     if (code == CURLE_OK) {
104         char *url = nullptr;
105         auto rc = curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);
106         if (rc == CURLE_OK && url && check_url) {
107             int http_code;
108             curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
109             if (http_code == 200)
110                 BB_VERBOSE("[OK] %s\n", url);
111             else
112                 BB_Warn("[ERROR] http code:%d, url: %s\n", http_code, url);
113         }
```

Use gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(gdb) f 5
#5  0x00002aaaac7b79a3 in bb_curl::check_result (this=0x6572f0, code=CURLE_OK, handle=0x6f4ab0,
check_url=true) at /wsp/bb_curl.cpp:110
110                     BB_VERBOSE("[OK] %s\n", url);
(gdb) p url
$1 = 0x2aaa00000000 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2aaa00000000>
```

I also set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1,`, can't fix it.

### UPDATE

platform:

1. gcc (GCC) 4.9.3
2. curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2e zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.10 libssh2/0.19.0-20080814
3. SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

I update the complete source code.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

/* reserved vector */
template <class T>
inline std::vector<T> bb_reserved_vector(size_t n) {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.reserve(n);
    return vec;
}

size_t write_cb(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    return size * nmemb;
}

bool check_result(CURLcode code, CURL *handle, bool check_url) {
    if (code == CURLE_OK && handle != nullptr) {
        char *url = nullptr;
        auto rc = curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);
        if (rc == CURLE_OK && url && check_url) {
            int http_code;
            curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
            if (http_code == 200)
                printf("[OK] %s\n", url);
            else
                printf("[ERROR] http code:%d, url: %s\n", http_code, url);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        printf("[ERROR] curl code %d\n", code);
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t sz = 1000;
    auto futures = bb_reserved_vector<std::future<CURLcode>>(sz);
    auto handles = bb_reserved_vector<CURL *>(sz);
    auto results = std::vector<std::string>(sz);

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        handles.push_back(curl_easy_init());
        int curl_code = curl_easy_setopt(handles[i], CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &results[i]);
        curl_code += curl_easy_setopt(handles[i], CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com");
        curl_code += curl_easy_setopt(handles[i], CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
        curl_code += curl_easy_setopt(handles[i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_code += curl_easy_setopt(handles[i], CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        if (curl_code != 0)
            printf("Set option error\n");
        auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, curl_easy_perform, handles[i]);
        futures.push_back(std::move(fut));
    }

    // synchronize
    for (size_t i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i) {
        futures[i].wait();
        check_result(futures[i].get(), handles[i], true);
    }

    // cleanup
    for (auto &item : handles)
        curl_easy_cleanup(item);

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The documentation says it's either null or it points to private memory, so I don't know what "sometimes" means in this context.

Comment: I means if send multi requests and check result, for some handlers, they be segfault, but others not. If either null or it points to private memory, then how this options work?

Comment: Private memory just means it's owned by curl, not that you can't access it. My guess is the call actually fails, so it leaves behind garbage in the pointer. What's the return value of `curl_easy_getinfo`?

Comment: Check the returned `CURLcode` to make sure `curl_easy_getinfo` succeeded. If it is not `CURLE_OK` Crom only knows what `url` points at.

Comment: I tried to check the result, still not work. I update the code.

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7. The crash happened only on CentOS. On Ubuntu I got output of either `[ERROR] curl code 7` or
`[OK] HTTP://www.example.com/`, but no crash at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you made a small but fatal error. The type of `http_code` should be `long` instead of `int`. Apparently, the call to `curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code)` overwrote the memory used by `url` on CentOS. Making this change fixed the crash on CentOS for me. Please be aware that `long` on 64-bit Linux is 8 bytes, longer than `int`.

Comment: thank you for this answer, I made the same mistake. It works correctly on windows but when I ported to Linux I get a segfault as well. Must be a difference between how int is defined between the two systems.

Comment: @GCB613 Yes, `long` is the same length between both Win32 and Win64 (for compatibility), but different between x86 and x86-64 Linux (more naturally).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the bug is not in the code you posted. It might be that you sometimes pass an invalid `CURL* handle`.

I checked this and indeed, if you pass an invalid handle, the function `curl_easy_getinfo` still returns `CURLE_OK`. A segmentation fault occurs later if you try to access the `char* url` variable. The propgram (compile with `g++ main.cpp -lcurl`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    char* url;
    CURL *handle;
    handle=curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
    CURL *bug=(CURL*)((long)(handle)+1);
    CURLcode code= curl_easy_getinfo(bug, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);    
    cout<<"CURLE_OK="<<CURLE_OK<< " and code="<<code<<endl;
    cout <<"URL: "<<url; //This line causes segmentation fault;
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

produces something like:

```
CURLE_OK=0 and code=0
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Comment: Update the complete source code, maybe not related to the handle issue.